# Add 150 grams to each order for calculating shipping

Tags: commerce

how can I add 150 grams to each order for calculating shipping costs (this weight corresponds to the packaging)?
I looked in the rules, but I do not see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using [commerce_shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) module, if so, you can add a [commerce_flat_rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) service to every order.

Otherwise I would suggest you start using these modules ;)

Comment: I already use two modules and I created several shipping modes. What I would like to do is add 150 grams on each order

Comment: so, what modules do you use ?? simplest would be to add a amount by flat rate. if you need to use the weight tariff, you probably should add this 150 grams to the product instance, before it's added to the cart, maybe here: http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_product_add/DC

Comment: I use the two modules that you quoted above. The link does not work. I have 15 shipping service in fixed and I want a rule to create to add the 150 grams has all shipping method.

Comment: after searching all day, there are no rules to add weight to an order. I think that the modules "Physical Fields" and "Trade Physical Product" can not do this.

Comment: commerce api seems to be down ... the mentioned method is hook_commerce_cart_add_product